# How to display fullCalendar default view to day wise from month wise?

Tags: php, laravel, calendar

I'm using [this calendar](https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar)
I want to display the calendar in day wise from month wise, by default it shows a monthly.

I am working on laravel 5.2.

Please let me know how to do it?

Comment: On the top of [this documentation page](https://fullcalendar.io/views/basicDay/) are 3 buttons with day, week and month. I assume you mean the day view? Or do you want the week view?

Comment: And please, show us the controller code where you create the calendar

Comment: Yes Mr.Douwe de Haan, in that I need day view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you've added the events to the calendar, you can set options for the calendar:

```
$calendar = Calendar::addEvents($events)->setOptions([
    'defaultView' => 'agendaDay'
]);
```

All the types of defaultViews are found [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/).